# How to override existing plugin action with new action

Tags: plugin-development, actions

I'm using a plugin. It has an action like this.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'old_action');
function old_action($pid) {
    "code goes here"
    }
}
```

I'm writing a module for this plugin. So i need to override that old action function with my new action function.

This is my new function.

```
function new_action($pid) {
      "code goes here"
        }
    }
```

I want to replace that old_action function with my new_action function using hooks. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the `remove_action()` function, like this:

```
remove_action('publish_post', 'old_action');
add_action('publish_post', 'new_action');
```

It's important to note that if the old_action was added with a priority parameter, you must add that to the `remove_action` call, otherwise it will fail to remove it. There are other implications if the old_action was added within a class. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) for more info.

Comment: +1 with the clarification that the remove action must be called after the function it is removing is added.

Comment: 'after_setup_theme' seems like a good place for remove_action. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170663/remove-action-on-after-setup-theme-not-working-from-child-theme

Comment: I tried for quite some time and was scratching my head - in the end "after_setup_theme" made it work! Thanks!