# remove_action on after_setup_theme not working from child theme

Tags: functions, themes, actions, child-theme

I am trying to remove a theme action for an elegant-themes theme using a child theme..
This works when I remove action after add_action code anywhere in the parent theme functions.php.
However, it does not work when I add it from child theme functions.php.

```
remove_action ('after_setup_theme', 'et_pb_setup_theme' , 10);
```

Remove action has same priority 10 as the add action. Shouldn't it work?

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'et_pb_setup_theme' ); //parent theme add_action
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As @cybmeta already pointed out, you are too early with your removal. So you have to defer the actual removal, for instance like so:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdev_170663_remove_parent_theme_stuff', 0 );

function wpdev_170663_remove_parent_theme_stuff() {

    remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'et_pb_setup_theme' );
}
```

Comment: Worked! I have been trying something similar, but my bad! Since I put a condition using **has_action** to check a _still non-existent_ action in child functions.php, before **remove_action** it wasn't working!! Thanks a lot! 

`function etn(){
    if(has_action('after_setup_theme', 'et_pb_setup_theme')){
        remove_action ('after_setup_theme', 'et_pb_setup_theme' );
    }
}
add_action ('after_setup_theme', 'etn', 9);`

Answer (score 4):

The functions.php file of child themes is loaded right before the parent theme functions.php, so when you run `remove_action` in child theme, the action you are trying to remove doesn't exist beacuse it is added later.

Comment: ..but doesn't priority 10 and the hook after_setup_theme should take care of that? How should I do this anyway?

Comment: No, the priority argument is not for that. Simply you can not remove something that doesn't exist. In other words, (taken from [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)) you cannot successfully remove the action before it has been added.

Comment: So, how is it possible to remove an action set by the parent theme?

Answer (score 2):

Try (just change the names):

```
add_action( 'init' , 'myyy_remove' , 15 );
function myyy_remove() {
        remove_action('ACTION_NAME', 'my_function_name_Something'   ,11);
        remove_action('ACTION_NAME', 'my_function_name_Another'     ,11);
}
```