# How to remove products-links after the product title using remove_action

Tags: plugins, themes, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

I'm trying to remove the navigation between products that appears right after the product title in my products pages.

The navigation is set in the `woocommerce.php` file of my theme:

```
/**
 * Class for all WooCommerce template modification
 *
 * @version 1.0
 */
class MrBara_WooCommerce {

    ...

    /**
     * Hooks to WooCommerce actions, filters
     *
     * @since  1.0
     * @return void
     */
    function hooks() {
        ...

        // Add prev/next product
        if ( in_array( mrbara_theme_option( 'product_page_layout' ), array( '1', '2', '8', '9', '12' ) ) ) {
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'products_links' ), 0 );
        }

        ...

    /**
     * Display products link
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    function products_links() {
        if ( function_exists( 'is_product' ) && ! is_product() ) {
            return;
        }

        $prev_link = '<span class="ion-ios-arrow-back"></span>';
        $next_link = '<span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span>';

        ...

        ?>
        <div class="products-links">
            <?php
            previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', $prev_link );
            next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', $next_link );
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I'm just starting understand how Wordpress work, and for what I've learn until now, I think I have to remove the action `products_links`.

**Test 1**

So, in my `functions.php` in my child theme, I've wrote this:

```
// Remove previous and next link in the product title
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_products_links');
function remove_products_links() {
    remove_action('products_links', 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
}
```

I added my "remove function" to the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` as the action that adds the products links is hooked to it.

But this doesn't work.

So I gone deeper in the documentation

But this not worked.

So, digging deeper in the Wordpress' documentation, I read this:

> If an action has been added from within a class, for example by a
>   plugin, removing it will require accessing the class through a
>   variable that holds the class instance. Unless the function is static
>   in which case you could call the class and function directly.

So, this is my case! My action is added by the class `MrBara_WooCommerce` in the method `hooks()` and the action's method `products_links()` isn't static, so I need to call the class, too.

**Test 2**

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_products_links');
function remove_products_links() {
    remove_action('products_links', ['MrBara_WooCommerce', 'woocommerce_single_product_summary'] );
}
```

Also this didn't work.

I've also tried to play with priorities, setting my `remove_products_links` at `9`, at `11`, at `10` and at `0` (to match the priority of the original added action) but nothing of this worked.

I think I'm very close to the solution but my inexperience causes me to miss some relevant settings.

Can you help me better understand why my `remove_action` doesn't work?

**UPDATE**

Continuing reading I've discovered that the `functions.php` file of my child theme is loaded BEFORE the files of the parent theme (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170665/57145).

I've had a perception of this printing the entire `$wp_filter` variable using the `functions.php` file of the child theme.

So, printing, I saw the `remove_products_links` action that I registered, but didn't saw the `products_links` action that I'm trying to remove.

So I thought that there must be some problems in the registered order.

Now, I think that I can't remove the action as when I register the remove action the action that I want to remove doesn't exist.

**The question, so, becomes: how can I remove an action from the parent theme using the child theme?**

Comment: I've added some things to look at based on your update. In and out today, but those hooks may help. I'll clean up my answer later on ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, you're correct that removing the action calling the `products_links` method would work, and that this is specifically `MrBara_WooCommerce->products_links()`.

In your *functions.php*, you can just use `remove_action` without wrapping it in a function used as a callback for another `add_action`, btw.

so:
`remove_action('products_links, array('MrBara_WooCommerce', 'woocommerce_single_product_summary, 0)` 10 is default priority, and while we may assume your priority needs to be higher than the `add_action` so it is called to remove it after it is included, WP codex notes this:

> To remove an action the priority must match the priority with with the
>   function was originally added.

And

> You cannot successfully remove the action before it has been added.
>
> You also cannot remove an action after it has been run.

So, one issue you're having may be that by hooking an `add_action` with a default priority (10) to call a function that does the `remove action` with a 0 priority, is doing so after the action with a zero priority has been run.

### Child versus Parent

Since child theme functions.php runs before the parent, you need to hook this after the theme is set up. `[wp_loaded]`[1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded), `[after_setup_theme]`[1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded), and `init` are possible options here.

an example using our earlier back and forth:

```
function remove_products_links() {
    global $mrbara;
    remove_action('product_links', array($mrbara, 'woocommerce_single_product_summary') );
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_products_links');
```

---

### original answer

The second argument needs to be an array like so:

```
remove_action('products_links', array('MrBara_WooCommerce', 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ) );
```

To access it from a global variable that holds the class, something like:

```
global $mrbara;
$mrbara = new MrBara_WooCommerce();
function remove_product_links() {
    global $mrbara;
    remove_action('product_links', array($mrbara, 'woocommerce_single_product_summary') );
}

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_products_links');
```

Comment: `['MrBara_WooCommerce', 'woocommerce_single_product_summary'` is an array: is the short syntax.
Anyway I've just tried to use `global $mrbara` but it doesn't work. In your example you use once `$mbara` to instantiate the class and `$mrbara` to assign it as a global variable: is mistyping or is intended?

Comment: the $mbara/$mrbara was just a typo. I realize that's the array short syntax, just trying to eliminate issues. Also, - not solving the above, but possibly achieving your end goal -, since _woocommerce.php_ is a theme file, you could just override it with your child theme and remove that bit.

Comment: I don't like to completely override the `woocommerce.php` file as this is a dirty way of achieving my result. Wordpress provides a powerful system to do things and I'd like to use it... My primary goal is to better understand how does it work... and for the moment I haven't reached the goal! -.-' I want to use hooks and add/remove_action() as this is the correct way to do things...

Comment: It's not dirty at all, it's the intended use of the template system. I admit it's off topic though. :) without trying it, I would think priority 0 may be needed. I'll look at it again and add some details when at a computer.

Comment: I've update my question: there is a problem in the order of loading `functions.php`: the child theme's one is loaded before the parent theme's one and this causes the issue: I cannot remove an action that doesn't already exist. The question now is how to intercept the parent's action from the child's `functions.php` file...

Comment: In your code you initialize `MrBara_WooCommerce` but it is initialized by the parent theme too. So, I'm removing from a class that is not the one that register the action and as result anyway I cannot remove the action successfully. I simply  came up with two copies of the same `MrBara_WooCommerce`. In the mean time I'm reading this: https://www.codementor.io/aaronoverton/wordpress-development-best-practices-oop-php-du107pcek Here the author uses `global $skeleton; \n $skeleton = new PluginSkeleton();`.

Comment: So I now know that the best practice is to initialize the class assigning it to a global variable. The problem is that the vendor of my theme initializes the class but doesn't assign it to a global variable, so for me is not possible to access it... I'm doing more tests to prove this theory...

Comment: I have an `after_setup_theme` hook set by the parent theme but I still miss the `global $mrBara` variable as the class is initialized without assigning it to any variable also if the actions are set using something like `dd_filter( 'add_to_cart_fragments', array( $this, 'add_to_cart_fragments' ) );`, so using `$this` that is actually the `MrBara_WooCommerce` class itself...+